# Does a Catch all catch an aggregate exception? and prevent crashing?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, xamarin

Would this cause an app to crash? Visual studio picks up the exception, but is that just because it's an IDE? Would this be ok in production? Or do I need to explicitly catch an AggregateException?

```
try
{
    throw new AggregateException;
}
catch
{
    What will happen?
}
```

Comment: You should do some reading on how Exceptions work in c#, that will save you a lot of trouble down the road. [Exceptions and Exception Handling (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/exceptions/),
[Exception Handling (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/exceptions/exception-handling)

Comment: You can try it right now and report back with any further questions: [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A "`catch all`" will catch all exceptions including `AggregateException` which is just a normal exception (which aggregates other exceptions). So in your case, nothing in perticular will happen. The exception will be caught and nothing more will happen.

"`Catch all`" is normally not recommended. It may hide unexpected errors and put your app in a broken state. In some rare cases it can be motivated though.